# Can I actually do anything during the race?

Tags: grand-prix-story

Is there anything I can do during the racing section that has any impact, or is it purely just for show?

I notice that when I press on the box containing the driver and car information it throbs, suggesting that it may have some kind of effect, but if it does I have no idea what...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than activate auras, nope.  All of your management and training comes into play during the race, but you're relegated to being a spectator, just like an actual business owner.

Tapping your driver's box is to switch views to the other driver, once you get two of them.

Comment: If my driver has an aura on race day I can press that button to activate it? Presumably for a speed boost or something?

Comment: There is a button that activates the aura, but I don't believe it's the driver's box.  It only shows up when you have an aura, I think.